# Unable to extract the zip64 archive using ZipInputStream with Java7 and Java8

Tags: java, zip, compression, zipinputstream, apache-commons-compress

I am using the below code to extract the files from zip archive.

```
public static List<String> unzipFiles(File zipFile, File targetDirectory) {
    List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = null;
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                fileInputStream));
        ZipEntry zipEntry;
        int count = 0;
        while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            log.debug("Extracting File Name :: " + zipEntry);
            count++;
            int length;
            byte data[] = new byte[bufferGlb];
            String fileName = zipEntry.getName();
            File opFile = new File(targetDirectory, fileName);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(opFile);
            dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream, bufferGlb);
            while ((length = zipInputStream.read(data, 0, bufferGlb)) != -1) {
                dest.write(data, 0, length);
            }
            dest.flush();
            files.add(fileName);
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }
        log.debug("Total " + count + " Files Unziped Successfully ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error occured in unzipping the file " + zipFile, e);
    }
}
```

This code works fine with normal zip archives but not with zip64 archive. As far as I know that Java7/Java8 (ZipInputStream class) should support zip64 but am getting the below exception .

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 0 but got 21504 bytes)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:384)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:196)
```

However am able to extract files from zip64 using the commons-compress ZipArchiveInputStream.

Any idea why the same can't be achieved using the Java API (ZipInputStream).

Comment: This issue is being faced by a lot of people yet we dont have any proper answer. Please help

Comment: You are not on MacOS aren't you? Because it should be possible on the other platforms and newer MacOS installations.

Comment: Yes as not on MacOS, its windows10